# GXT 3 - The value of "Object" is null for a class which implements HasCell<C,T>

Tags: gwt, gxt, treegrid

I am trying to implement HasCell(C,T) in GXT 3. But, the overridden functions which uses object of type C is null.

```
public class ImageCell implements HasCell<SensorTreeModel, ImageResource>{

private ClickableImageResourceCell imageCell = new ClickableImageResourceCell();
private TextButtonCell textCell = new TextButtonCell();
@Override
public Cell<ImageResource> getCell() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return imageCell;
}

@Override
public FieldUpdater<SensorTreeModel, ImageResource> getFieldUpdater() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new FieldUpdater<SensorTreeModel, ImageResource>() {
          @Override
          public void update(int index, SensorTreeModel object, ImageResource value) {
              object.getName();
             Window.alert("image Clicked");
          }         
        };

}   

@Override
public ImageResource getValue(SensorTreeModel object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    return com.sencha.project.client.Resources.INSTANCES.add();     
}}
```

The value of object(SensorTreeModel) in getFieldUpdater as well as getValue are both null. Please do help. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: How are you using this cell? Whatever you are passing the cell to is responsible for giving it data, so this points at a messed up ValueProvider (assuming a GXT data widget), or data that just happens to be null.

Comment: Colin's right about the value provider. A IdentityValueProvider is an option to send the entire model to the cell. An example of using HasCell here: http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/ui/cells/customcells/CompositeCell.html

Comment: @ColinAlworth Thanks. I was returning null from the ValueProvider. Got it working! :)